# Largest size of the automorphism group of a 3-regular graph on 12 vertices

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Let $ G $ be a 3-regular connected graph on 12 vertices. We also assume that $ G $ is undirected, unweighted, and simple.

What will be the largest possible size of the automorphism group of $ G $?

The example I found with a large automorphism group is a hexagonal prism, whose automorphism group is generated by (1 2 3 4 5 6)(7 8 9 10 11 12), (1 7)(2 8)(3 9)(4 10)(5 11)(6 12), and (2 6)(3 5)(8 12)(9 11), corresponding to a $\pi/6$ - rotation and reflections. This automorphism group has size 24.

[image]

Can anyone come up with an example with larger automorphism group?

Comment: According to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002851) there are only 85 $3$-regular graphs with 12 nodes (assuming I can use OEIS correctly). If I could only find how to call them up in Sage, it wouldn't take very long to brute-force it! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are 3-regular ("cubic") graphs with 12 nodes and more automorphisms, but not many.

It turns out that Wikipedia has a list of [simple cubic graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_simple_cubic_graphs#12_vertices) with up to 12 vertices! And it just so happens to list the size of their automorphism groups.

The list unfortunately does not number various graphs, which makes it hard to refer to them. But the skeleton of the hexagonal prism is indeed there near the end, having 24 automorphisms (and the truncated tetrahedron graph too!).

The most automorphisms appears to be 64, from:
[image]

```
G = Graph({1:[2, 4, 12], 2:[3, 5], 3:[4, 6], 4:[5], 5:[6], 6:[7], 7:[8, 10], 8:[9, 11], 9:[10, 12], 10:[11], 11:[12]}) #64 auto, but sage claims 16
print G.automorphism_group().cardinality(), "automorphisms\n"
G.plot()
```

Honorable mentions include this nifty-looking one with 48 automorphisms:
[image]

```
G = Graph({1:[2, 11, 12], 2:[3, 12], 3:[4, 5], 4:[5, 6], 5:[6], 6:[7], 7:[8, 9], 8:[9, 10], 9:[10], 10:[11], 11:[12]})
print G.automorphism_group().cardinality(), "automorphisms\n"
G.plot() #48 auto
```

And the stately [Franklin Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_graph), also with 48 automorphisms (nicer drawing on Wikipedia):
[image]

```
G = graphs.FranklinGraph()
print G.automorphism_group().cardinality(), "automorphisms\n"
G.plot()
```

And because I already took a screenshot and wrote out its connections, I'll include this weirdo with 32 automorphisms:
[image]

```
L = [[0,1], [0,6], [0,11], [1,2], [1,4],
[2,3], [2,5], [3,4], [3,6], [4,5],
[5,6], [7,8], [7,9], [7,11], [8,9],
[8,10], [9,10], [10,11]]
G = Graph([tuple(thing) for thing in L]) #32 auto
print G.automorphism_group().cardinality(), "automorphisms\n"
G.plot()
```

EDIT: As an addendum, it turns out that the [LCF notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCF_notation) given in the table is actually quite handy for referring to the graphs. Take the 2nd to last example in the table, listed as having LCF notation $[6, 6, −3, −5, 5, 3]^2$. We can ask Sage to work with such a graph by calling

```
import networkx
K = networkx.LCF_graph(12, [6, 6, -3, -5, 5, 3], 2)
G = Graph(K)
```

using the NetworkX documentation for LCF notation [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.generators.small.LCF_graph.html). Unfortunately the `−` symbol on Wikipedia isn't a symbol that Sage recognizes, so you'll have to replace those with the `-` symbol your keyboard produces.

Comment: Code above can be copied to [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) and ran

Comment: Thanks so much! Ironically the one with 64 automorphisms does not look very symmetric though... :)

Comment: No problem, I was hoping for a way to get Sage to do *all* the work, but no such luck. And I initially typed in an extra edge for the first one, causing Sage to tell me there were only 16 automorphisms; I had to convince myself there really were 64, because you're right that it's not the most symmetric-looking!

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to uses gene (from the nauty package) to generate and write the graphs to a file, and then read that into sage.

Comment: Oops, for `gene' read `geng'.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Thanks, I had heard of nauty, but never really looked into using it. It sounds like I should find a reason to, at some point!